# How can i add a button to a form, but have it still be in the designer view once the program terminates

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I need to add a button onto a form, but have it still be there once the program terminates.
I have tried doing:

```
Form.Contols.add(NewBTN)
```

but this does not place the button permanently onto the form.

Thanks in advance
Finn

Comment: That is not possible. A button in the designer is just created by interpreting code from a plain-text file, whilst a button in an application is compiled instructions on how to create it, render it and how it should behave.

Comment: Add it in the designer? Or you need to be more specific about what exactly your goal is.

Comment: @Trevor : It seems he wants to add buttons dynamically at run-time, then when he closes the app have the changes reflected **both** in the source and the already compiled application.

Comment: @VisualVincent, yes that's what I thought too.. but it's so out there, I figured I may be missing something in the question...

Comment: @Trevor : I don't think you are... While it may seem "out there" to us, newer programmers might not fully understand the difference between design-time and run-time (which is perfectly obvious to us who have much experience).

Comment: @Trevor : Depending on how new the programmer is, he/she might just think of it as "It exists when I run the program, which looks exactly like in Visual Studio, so why couldn't changes be made the other way around?".

Comment: @VisualVincent, you are probably right... nothing would surprise me any more :)

Comment: Do you want that button to have a click event as well, or just be visually in the design when running the program again?